# How to create a proper ortographic camera in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

So I am having a little hard time understanding how ortographic cameras work in libgdx.

what I want is to have a camera that will only render things within a square while having another camera set the bounds for my whole screen.

[image]

So here, I was able to do what I wanted on the whole screen for the game pad. But, the thing you see on the top right is the background map of the game and i want to render the parts only fall within the red square you see here. How do I achieve that?

Are cameras supposed to do that or do I need to figure out a way to do it manually? I am really confused as to how cameras and projection matrices work.

Here on this screen, The red square and the green pad on the left are being drawn using the projection matrix of my screen camera. The map(top right) is drawn using my map cam.

Map cam is a view port of 400x400  but as you can see , the tiles are rectangular and that isnt the aspect ration i want. If someone can briefly explain how cameras work , I'd greatly appreciate it.

The reason I am not posting my code here is because I feel like I need to understand how camera mechanics work to even code it properly so I want to address that issue first.

Following @Tenfour04's advice worked perfectly. In case anyone wonders what I wanted to achieve. Here's a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A camera alone cannot crop off part of the screen. For that you need to use glViewport. There is already a Viewport class in Libgdx that can do that for you. You will need two orthographic cameras (one for the map and one for the GUI), but the viewport can create its own.

```
private Viewport viewport;

//in create:
viewport = new FitViewport(400, 400);

//in resize:
viewport.update(width, height);

//in render:
viewport.getCamera().position.set(/*...move your map camera as needed*/);
viewport.apply(); //viewport cropped to your red square
batch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
batch.begin();
//draw map
batch.end();

//return to full screen viewport
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); 

batch.setProjectionMatrix(yourGUICamera.combined);
batch.begin();
//draw gui
batch.end();
```

Comment: I had already used a similar pattern. I will try this and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, this worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!. I was just not applying and updating the viewports properly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What happens, is the camera will fit itself to the size of the screen.  In order to change this, you would want to use a [FrameBuffer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html). The frame buffer will constrain the camera into the desired size, then can be drawn as a texture.

Create the frame buffer with the dimensions being in pixels.

```
//Initialize the buffer
FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, width, helght, false);
```

Render the world within the buffer.

```
fbo.begin();

//Draw the world here

fbo.end();
```

Draw the buffer to the screen with a batch.

```
batch.begin();

batch.draw(fbo.getColorBufferTexture(), x, y);

batch.end();
```

Comment: RGB888 is not supported for FrameBuffers on all devices, so you would need RGB565 as a backup, and so colors would be low-fi on those devices.